# How do I reference the first index of lists of lists?

Tags: python, list

I've written the code below:

```
items = [[1,91],[1,92],[2,93],[2,97],[1,60],[2,77],[1,65],[1,87],[1,100],[2,100],[2,76]]

sorted_items = sorted(items, key=lambda x: x[0])

for i in sorted_items:
    if i[0] == (i+1)[0]:
```

The above code gives me an error- particularly for the last line of code. My question is, how do I reference the first index of lists within lists? I hope the question is clear from the last line of my code.

i.e. i[0] is okay, but Python doesn't allow (i+1)[0]; how else can I write this?

Thanks.

Just a follow on from my question above:

```
for i in range(len(sorted_items)-1):
    if sorted_items[i][0] == sorted_items[i+1][0]:
        final_sorted_items = sorted(sorted_items, key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)

print(final_sorted_items)
```

So I have added the line but it doesn't do the job that I am after. I basically want to sort the smaller lists in descending order if the first index is the same. Any idea how to amend my code to do this? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

That `i` you're trying to use like `i+1` is a `list` already. If you want to achieve this, you should use `range`.

```py
    items = [[1,91],[1,92],[2,93],[2,97],[1,60],[2,77],[1,65],[1,87],[1,100],[2,100],[2,76]]

    sorted_items = sorted(items, key=lambda x: x[0])

    for i in range(0, len(sorted_items)-1):
        if sorted_items[i][0] == sorted_items[i+1][0]:
            #do your stuff
```

Comment: Just added the len(sorted_items)-1 to your code, otherwise it will crash on the last index cause you lookup for i+1 (index out of range).

Comment: I missed that part, thanks for correcting it.

Comment: Also, the last line of code, is it meant to read sorted_items[i+1][0] ; or is the (i+1) meant to be in circular brackets?

Comment: Oh, you're right, it should be [] not (), my bad again. Sorry for rush answer. I edited and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
items = [[1,91],[1,92],[2,93],[2,97],[1,60],[2,77],[1,65],[1,87],[1,100],[2,100],[2,76]]

sorted_items = sorted(items, key=lambda x: x[0])

for i in range(len(sorted_items)-1):
    if sorted_items[i][0] == sorted_items[i+1][0]:
        pass
```

I don't know what is the purpose of your code, but if you want to get all list elements such as value at index 0 of element is equal to value at index 0 of next element in list then you could:

```
l = [ sorted_items[i] for i in range(len(sorted_items)-1) if sorted_items[i][0] == sorted_items[i+1][0] ]
```

Comment: The purpose is to first identify all of the (smaller) lists with the same 0th index; which your code above does just fine. But then for those with the same 0th index, I want to sort by the 1st index (i.e. the higher scores) in descending order. So for example if we had [[1,91] , [1,92] , [1,93 ]]  ->.    [[1,93] , [1,92] , [1,91]]